# MongoClient.Connect with Nodejs not authenticating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are running a MongoDb with some nodejs on an ubuntu server (one instance).
When trying to connect using MongoClient.Connect it fails with "Authentication fails".

**Versions:**
Ubuntu v22.04.03
MongoDb Community v7.04
NodeJs v20.10.0
Node Mongo driver 6.4.0

Steps:

1. Created "admin" user in admin dbs.  role: root, Db: admin
2. Set /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service in ExecStart with parameter --auth
3. Password was verified in Mongosh

When trying to connect we do the following:

```
var { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
var ODataServer = require("simple-odata-server");
var Adapter = require('simple-odata-server-mongodb');

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/ourNewDb", {
        auth: { 
            authSource: "admin",
            username: "admin",
            password: "ourPassword"
        },
    }, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        odataServer.adapter(Adapter(function(cb) {  //will use simple-odata-server-mongodb
            return console.log("success"); 
            cb(err, db.db("ourNewDb")); 
        }));
    });
```

You will notice we are using authSource because we are connecting to a different dbs while authenticating against admin.

According to the documentation auth object needs "user" not "username" but we got an error on that and changed it.

The full error returned is:

```
 Uncaught MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.sendCommand (/collaborit-mwm-admin-portal/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:278:27)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.command (/collaborit-mwm-admin-portal/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:301:26)
    at async executeScram (/collaborit-mwm-admin-portal/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/scram.js:79:22)
    at async performInitialHandshake (/collaborit-mwm-admin-portal/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:101:13)
    at async connect (/collaborit-mwm-admin-portal/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:19:9) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
```

This same code used to work on earlier releases of Mongo.  Is there something we are missing from the documentation.  Its been a few days now of constant searching and trying.

UPDATE
Mongod.log indicates UserNotFound for db ourNewDb ... yet the auth db is specified as "admin", so obviously something wrong in specifying the authSource.  We could just create a user in ourNewDb but that still does not answer the question.

Here is the mongod.log

```
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2024-03-08T07:14:57.515+02:00"
  },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "ACCESS",
  "id": 5286307,
  "ctx": "conn338",
  "msg": "Failed to authenticate",
  "attr": {
    "client": "127.0.0.1:40518",
    "isSpeculative": false,
    "isClusterMember": false,
    "mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-1",
    "user": "admin",
    "db": "Collaborit_MWM_Server",
    "error": "UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"Collaborit_MWM_Server\"",
    "result": 11,
    "metrics": {
      "conversation_duration": {
        "micros": 375,
        "summary": {
          "0": {
            "step": 1,
            "step_total": 2,
            "duration_micros": 352
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extraInfo": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the mongod log say about the failure?

Comment: Are you sure, you created the user in `admin` database? How did you create it?

Comment: use admin
db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"ourPassword", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})

Comment: Maybe try to put the credentials into the connection string instead of `auth` option.

Comment: How are you connecting to the server using the same credentials - with mongosh?

Comment: Also, refer this: [Authentication Mechanisms - NodeJS driver docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/authentication/mechanisms/)

Comment: After dropping ourNewDb in mongosh and recreating it the problem disappeared, just like that .. gone